# How to build an array when some values are retrieved asynchronosly through callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

I am attempting to build a JavaScript function that will return an array of destinations based on some user input. Some of the input can be put directly into the array (such as when the user enters an address). Other times I nee to use the Google Places API to translate places (i.e. hardware store) into real world destinations. The problem is that these destinations are returned asynchronously through callbacks. How do I build up and then use the array when I have these locations coming in at all different times through callbacks?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function parseDestinations(){
    var listItems = $('#InputBoxesList').children();
    var destinations = [];
    for(var i=0; i< listItems.length;i++){
        var selector = $(listItems[i]).children('.locationTypeSelector')[0];
        var locationInputBox = $(listItems[i]).children('.locationInput')[0];
        var selectedValue = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value.replace('select_','');

        if(selectedValue == selectTypes.Address.value){
            destinations.push({
                location: locationInputBox.value,
                stopover: true
            });
            calcRouteFromCurrentLocation(destinations);
        }
        else if(selectedValue == selectTypes.GenericLocation.value){
            var type = [];
            type.push(locationInputBox.value);
            var request = {
                location: currentLocation,
                types: type,
                rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE 
            };
            placesService.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status){

                //I don't know what to do here...

            });
        }
        else if(selectedValue == selectTypes.Chain.value){
            alert('Searching by Chain not supported yet');
        }
        else if(selectedValue == selectTypes.Item.value){
            alert('Searching by Item not supported yet');
        }

    }
    return destinations;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I should deal with this?

Comment: You need to use deferred objects: look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the [async flow control library](https://github.com/caolan/async). If you learn it, your complex asynchronous code will become more clean and manageable and less ad-hoc and cowboy coded.

```
async.parallel(destinations, function (destination, callback) {
    //if need an async call, do
    lookupDestination(destination, function (result) {
        //tell async this one is done
        callback(null, result);
    });
    //otherwise if you don't need a async call, just
    return callback(null, lookupSync(destination));
}, function (error, done) {
    //now `done` is a list of resolved destinations
    //go to town
});
```